# What could I use to automatically generate daily reports on my web app?

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, sql-server

I've written a simple report building web application with ASP.NET and SQL that essentially generates a CSV report when the user submits a form. All that works fine, but I was wondering if there is any way to automate the submission process. For example, could I write a program or a daemon to submit the form or send POST data to the page every 24 hours and download the reports automatically? I can't find any tools to do this, but it seems possible. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You seem to have answered your own question, in the question text. A daemon/service is one of the more accepted solutions to this type of problem.

Comment: Besides what's already mentioned, you can use a background task library like hangfire(http://hangfire.io/) to schedule these tasks for you.  You're already using asp.net and sql server so it should fit in pretty easily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'non-specific' nature of this report generation means that tools aren't usually employed to assist with this.  Instead, you would (as you said) use a scheduled task or a cron job to invoke a URL at a regular interval.  You can also forego a console application using an `HttpWebRequest` and just use [curl](http://curl.haxx.se/dlwiz/?type=bin&os=Win32&flav=-&ver=2000%2FXP) even on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create one windows scheduled task which we will run after every 24 hours.
2. You can execute batch file using this scheduled task. Just by giving the path of the batch file. This batch file will execute one VB script code written in separate file.
3. Batch file should contain this line `cscript.exe report.vbs`
4. report.vbs should contain following code:

   Const URL = "http://demo.com/auto_generate_report.aspx"
   '===========================================
   Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
   Set iE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
   IE.Visible = True
   With IE
   .Navigate2 URL
   While Not .ReadyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
   wscript.sleep 1000
   Wend
   wscript.sleep 60000
   .Quit
   End With
   Set IE = Nothing
5. You can write logic to generate report in page load of the page which you have called using scheduled task.